# iOS - (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Tags: objective-c, ssl, nsurlconnection, tls1.2, afnetworking-3

I'm getting **(kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)** when connecting to a client's server.

The client's server has a self signed certificate that I can not change. The app is using AFNetworking 3.x. I've tried the following but nothing seems to work.

If someone could help me, it will be much appreciated.

Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>

        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key> *** CLIENT HOSTNAME *** </key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>

    </dict>
```

AFNetworking connection manager:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

#ifdef USE_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_RULES
    manager.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    manager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = YES;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried your solution but it did not work. Settings **allowInvalidCertificates** , **validatesDomainName** and **AFSSLPinningModeCertificate** did not solved my problem. After going through lots of googling I saw the structure of **AFSecurityPolicy** this class.

There is a function in this class

```
- (BOOL)evaluateServerTrust:(SecTrustRef)serverTrust
              forDomain:(nullable NSString *)domain;
```

You have to subclass the **AFSecurityPolicy** and return **YES** in its implementation. Then you will be able to connect to your server.

My client server was also self-signed.

Settings properties on  **AFSecurityPolicy** does not solve the problem, I wonder why.

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, it worked like a charm. I did what you said, I subclassed evaluateServerTrust: then called it in setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock when needed.

Comment: @PerroVerde Could you please share the code here, I am trying to do the same; I have modified evaluateServerTrust, after pinning I get result as kSecTrustResultUnspecified, but SSL still fails.