# HTTP load failed and I have tried all of the SO suggestions, but nothing works

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, ios10, nsurlrequest

Error 9802 is a "Fatal Alert" according to the Apple's [docs](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-32463/lib/SecureTransport.h).  I have looked at Google and SO and found nothing referencing 9802 that fixes this problem.  I can change my code to go for "apple.com" and I get the page, but using my own URL, I get the error above.  I have tried everything that I can think of, and nothing works.  Time to ask for help! :D

The result of using

> /usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://pragerphoneapps.com

is all tests fail (results are uploaded [*here*](http://pastebin.com/jEUKqW1G))

This is an image of my app's .plist file (only pertinent part)

[image]

and this is an image of the target info:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
- (IBAction)showHTMLHelp:(UIButton *)sender {

//  make the popover
UIViewController* popoverContent = [UIViewController new];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 450, 500)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)1.0 alpha:(CGFloat)1.0];  //  frame color?
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

//resize the popover view shown in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 500);

NSString *urlAddress = @"https://pragerphoneapps.com";     // @"https://www.pragerphoneapps.com/bookstore-inventory-manager/upload-help/";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//  add the UIWebView for RichText
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: popoverView.frame];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  //  change background color here

//  add the webView to the popover
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[popoverView addSubview:webView];

//  if previous popoverController is still visible... dismiss it
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

//create a popover controller
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)oShowHelp).frame inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: Does it work with http domains? if so then the problem is not likely your code. Check this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719075/ios-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9813

Comment: no... doesn't work with http or https; gives this error:   App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: your target site is compromised or the certs are bad. it won't even open in chrome.

Comment: for *https*:, you're right, it's not a secure site, but I was able to open it with *http*: and just *pragerphoneapps.com*

Comment: It appears I need a SSL Certificate on that domain (Apple's new requirements as of Jan 1, 2017); ordering it now, should be installed and working within 24 hours... I'll get back to you as soon as it's installed... thanks John... chat w/ u later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously recommend you to fix your SSL certificate.
ATS requires you to have a valid SSL certificate, TLS version 1.2 or above and support for forward secrecy. 
This will be a requirement at the beginning of 2017 so better get ready.

Anyway, meanwhile try the following steps to get this working.

Put this on top of your file:

```
@interface NSURLRequest (InvalidSSLCertificate)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString*)host;
+ (void)setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:(BOOL)allow forHost:(NSString*)host;
@end
```

Disable App Transport Security in Info.plist. 
[image]

Allow invalid SSL certificates before loading request:

```
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
```

Sample code that successfully loads your site:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"https://pragerphoneapps.com";     // @"https://www.pragerphoneapps.com/bookstore-inventory-manager/upload-help/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work... got this:  NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Comment: Getting a SSL Certificate fixed the problem; thanks for the hint!  SD

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why it can't work for setting "NSAllowArbitraryLoads to YES".If there are caches, try to reboot your Mac or Xcode.
And your "Exception Domains" settings have the wrong format.

[image]